# MySQL query slow or stuck on sending data

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following table schema in MySQL 5.5.37, the table has 1685412 rows so far and growing.

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tSource` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tStatus` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `tRef` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `externalEventID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eDescription` mediumtext,
  `eStatus` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'OK',
  `ePri` tinyint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
  `eSta` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dId` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dIp` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateCreated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dateUpdated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `externaltRef` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventNotes` text,
  `bId` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supp` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `processed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rString` text,
  `rUrl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rEsc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rEscO` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eCle` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ePri_count` (`supp`,`eStatus`,`dateCreated`,`tStatus`),
  KEY `event_device_date_status` (`eName`,`dName`,`dateUpdated`,`tStatus`),
  KEY `status_customer_date_tstatus` (`eStatus`,`customerName`,`dateCreated`,`tStatus`),
  KEY `ePri_count_top` (`supp`,`eStatus`,`processed`,`dateCreated`,`customerName`,`tStatus`),
  KEY `event_suppress` (`dateCreated`,`processed`,`supp`),
  KEY `related_events` (`dName`,`tRef`,`tStatus`,`processed`,`dateUpdated`),
  KEY `eName_eStatus_dName_date_proc` (`processed`,`eStatus`,`dName`,`dateCreated`,`eName`),
  KEY `proc_tStatus_customer_date_priority` (`processed`,`tStatus`,`customerName`,`dateCreated`,`ePri`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1685400 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

EXPLAIN 
SELECT ID AS id
     , tSource
     , eDescription
     , eName
     , dId
     , dIp
     , tRef
     , customerName
     , dName
     , ePri
     , dateCreated
     , tStatus
     , supp 
  FROM events  
 WHERE processed = 1 
   AND eStatus != 'OK' 
   AND tStatus = 'NEW' 
   AND tSource IN ('source_1', 'source_2', 'source_3', 'source_4', 'source_5') 
   AND dateCreated BETWEEN '2015-10-01 10:36:00' AND  '2015-10-16 10:44:00' 
 ORDER 
    BY dateCreated DESC;
```

The problem I have is the query takes a long time to complete if it ever completes, and on most occasions running a show processlist just has the query stuck on sending data so even the explain never returns anymore

Initially I thought the ORDER BY was causing an issue so I did this but it still doesnt work

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT ID AS id
            , tSource
            , eDescription
            , eName
            , dId
            , dIp
            , tRef
            , customerName
            , dName
            , ePri
            , dateCreated
            , tStatus
            , supp 
         FROM events e  
        WHERE processed = 1 
          AND eStatus != 'OK' 
          AND tStatus = 'NEW' 
          AND tSource IN ('source_1', 'source_2', 'source_3', 'source_4', 'source_5') 
          AND dateCreated BETWEEN '2015-10-01 10:36:00' AND  '2015-10-16 10:44:00'
     ) as e  
 ORDER  
    BY dateCreated DESC;
```

I also tried to check the database for corruption and it came back as ok

UPDATE: EXPLAIN now returns

```
-+------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                                                                                                        | key                                      | key_len | ref         | rows   | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ref  | status_customer_date_tstatus,event_suppress,eName_eStatus_dName_date_proc,proc_tStatus_customer_date_priority                        | proc_tStatus_customer_date_priority      | 21      | const,const | 996507 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

UPDATE: Profiling shows a most time is spent sorting the data - should I just sort this in the code rather that MySQL event when I used ORDER BY ID instead of DateCreated (I thought MySQL would be able to do this fairly quickly) - apologies for the formatting

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING WHERE QUERY_ID=2;
    +----------+-----+--------------------------------+------------+-----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------+-------------+
| QUERY_ID | SEQ | STATE                          | DURATION   | CPU_USER  | CPU_SYSTEM | CONTEXT_VOLUNTARY | CONTEXT_INVOLUNTARY | BLOCK_OPS_IN | BLOCK_OPS_OUT | MESSAGES_SENT | MESSAGES_RECEIVED | PAGE_FAULTS_MAJOR | PAGE_FAULTS_MINOR | SWAPS | SOURCE_FUNCTION       | SOURCE_FILE   | SOURCE_LINE |
+----------+-----+--------------------------------+------------+-----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------+-------------+
|        2 |   2 | starting                       |   0.000029 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | NULL                  | NULL          |        NULL |
|        2 |   3 | Waiting for query cache lock   |   0.000008 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | try_lock              | sql_cache.cc  |         454 |
|        2 |   4 | checking query cache for query |   0.000101 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | send_result_to_client | sql_cache.cc  |        1561 |
|        2 |   5 | checking permissions           |   0.000010 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | check_access          | sql_parse.cc  |        4786 |
|        2 |   6 | Opening tables                 |   0.000020 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | open_tables           | sql_base.cc   |        4831 |
|        2 |   7 | System lock                    |   0.000010 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_lock_tables     | lock.cc       |         299 |
|        2 |   8 | Waiting for query cache lock   |   0.000061 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | try_lock              | sql_cache.cc  |         454 |
|        2 |   9 | init                           |   0.000040 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_select          | sql_select.cc |        2579 |
|        2 |  10 | optimizing                     |   0.000023 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize              | sql_select.cc |         865 |
|        2 |  11 | statistics                     |   0.000259 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize              | sql_select.cc |        1056 |
|        2 |  12 | preparing                      |   0.000028 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize              | sql_select.cc |        1078 |
|        2 |  13 | executing                      |   0.000005 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | exec                  | sql_select.cc |        1836 |
|        2 |  14 | Sorting result                 | 999.999999 | 17.165073 |   5.588349 |             74361 |                1326 |      6687376 |        208944 |             0 |                 0 |                 1 |            111411 |     0 | exec                  | sql_select.cc |        2267 |
|        2 |  15 | Sending data                   |  57.755522 |  1.492093 |   0.364023 |              4331 |                 111 |       233040 |         10792 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |              2842 |     0 | exec                  | sql_select.cc |        2380 |
|        2 |  16 | end                            |   0.000021 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 1 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_select          | sql_select.cc |        2615 |
|        2 |  17 | query end                      |   0.000007 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc  |        4465 |
|        2 |  18 | closing tables                 |   0.000014 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc  |        4517 |
|        2 |  19 | freeing items                  |   0.000028 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_parse           | sql_parse.cc  |        5675 |
|        2 |  20 | logging slow query             |   0.000005 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | log_slow_statement    | sql_parse.cc  |        1479 |
|        2 |  21 | logging slow query             |   0.000063 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |            16 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | log_slow_statement    | sql_parse.cc  |        1488 |
|        2 |  22 | cleaning up                    |   0.000007 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | dispatch_command      | sql_parse.cc  |        1435 |
+----------+-----+--------------------------------+------------+-----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: There's not much point executing an EXPLAIN if you don't then show the result of the EXPLAIN.

Comment: Sorting 1.6 million rows takes some effort, but the query should be returning within a handful of minutes, at the most.  How many rows are being selected?

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of the subquery; it only adds overhead:

```
 SELECT ID, tSource, eDescription, eName, dId, dIp, tRef, customerName,
        dName, ePri, dateCreated, tStatus, supp 
 FROM events e  
 WHERE processed = 1 AND
       eStatus <> 'OK' AND
       tStatus = 'NEW' AND
       tSource IN ('source_1', 'source_2', 'source_3', 'source_4', 'source_5') AND
       dateCreated BETWEEN '2015-10-01 10:36:00' AND  '2015-10-16 10:44:00' 
 ORDER BY dateCreated DESC;
```

The best index for this query starts with `processed` and `tStatus`.  Then it should have another column, probably `dateCreated`.  So, this *might* be faster if the index is more selective:  `events(processed, tStatus, dateCreated)`.  You can throw in `eStatus` and `tSource` *after* these columns, so the `WHERE` clause is covered by the index.

This will not use the index for the `order by`.  Can you order by `id desc` instead of `dateCreated desc`?  It is a primary key and hence clustered (in MySQL) so you might be able to get around the final `order by`.

Comment: Here is some relevant reading on [MySQL multiple-column indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: Thanks Gordon, changing orderby to ID gets me further, at least I can run explain without it stuck on sending data :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with getting rid of the subquery, but suggest creating a covering index in the following context

index on... 
( processed, tstatus, tsource, datecreated, estatus )

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(processed, tStatus, dateCreated) -- should be pretty good in any version
INDEX(processed, tStatus, tSource, dateCreated) -- might work best in a new 5.6
```

Comment: still runs very slow, do you think the best option would be to partition on dateCreated to limit the rows it scans ?

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` show after adding my two indexes?

Comment: `PARTITION BY RANGE(dateCreated)` _may_ help.  But don't have more than about 50 partitions.  What MySQL version are you using?